# Scala Breeze DenseMatrix to SparseMatrix conversion

Tags: scala, breeze, sparse-matrix

Im struggeling to find a way to quickly convert a DenseMatrix to SparseMatrix.

I tried flattening the DenseMatrix to an array, converting it to a Sparse Matrix and then reshaping it but this is not possible since there is no reshape function..

```
val dm = DenseMatrix((1,2,3),(0,0,0),(0,0,0))
val sm =CSCMatrix(dm.toArray)
sm.reshape(3,3)
```

error: value reshape is not a member of breeze.linalg.CSCMatrix[Int]

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
val dm = DenseMatrix((1,2,3),(0,0,0),(0,0,0))
val sm = CSCMatrix.tabulate(dm.rows, dm.cols)(dm(_, _))
```